# how to write datetime in month year format in clean thesis?

Tags: datetime

I am using clean thesis for writing the thesis. But, I am unable to write datetime in month year format like (August 2016).

Comment: So you don't want the day showing? Are you referring to `\today`? Should this form part of your title (`\maketitle`)?

Comment: Please Gopal, learn how to ask proper qustions. It is very very **NOT** obvious to most what you mean by clean thesis.

Answer (score 3):

Define a `\MONTH` and `\YEAR` macro to set what you need. The following example highlights this within `\maketitle`'s `\date`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{cleanthesis}

\newcommand{\MONTH}{%
  \ifcase\month% 0
    \or January% 1
    \or February% 2
    \or March% 3
    \or April% 4
    \or May% 5
    \or June% 6
    \or July% 7
    \or August% 8
    \or September% 9
    \or October% 10
    \or November% 11
    \or December% 12
  \fi}
\newcommand{\YEAR}{\number\year}

\author{An author}
\title{A title}
\date{\MONTH\ \YEAR}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't recommend using `cleanthesis`. Anyway, the date format can be set with the `datetime2` package.

```
% **************************************************
% Document Class Definition
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
  paper=A4,                     % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
  twoside=true,                 % onesite or twoside printing
  openright,                    % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
  parskip=full,                 % spacing value / method for paragraphs
  chapterprefix=true,           % prefix for chapter marks
  11pt,                         % font size
  headings=normal,              % size of headings
  bibliography=totoc,           % include bib in toc
  listof=totoc,                 % include listof entries in toc
  titlepage=on,                 % own page for each title page
  captions=tableabove,          % display table captions above the float env
  draft=false,                  % value for draft version
  enabledeprecatedfontcommands,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % defines file's character encoding

\usepackage[                % clean thesis style
  figuresep=colon,
  sansserif=false,
  hangfigurecaption=false,
  hangsection=true,
  hangsubsection=true,
  colorize=full,
  colortheme=bluemagenta,
  bibsys=bibtex,
  bibfile=bib-refs,
  bibstyle=alphabetic,
]{cleanthesis}

\usepackage{datetime2,datetime2-calc}
\DTMnewdatestyle{Myyyy}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMmonthname{##2}~##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{Myyyy}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have used above command for month year date but our output date format in numeric (means month and year both appeared in numeric), Also want to  month in alphabetic, and year in numeric format.